# Ember.js hasMany Relationship Not Resolving before Render

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, promise

When I try to render a list of `view` models contained in a `chart` model using the `each` handlebars helper, the promise array for the `view` models doesn't resolve before the `each` helper renders, leaving blank `li`s:

[image: problem]

**template:**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="chart-container">
    {{views}}
    <ul>
        {{#each view in views}}
            <li>{{view}}</li>
        {{/each}}
    </ul>
</script>
```

What's odd is that if I change the `each` helper to `{{#each views}}` it works fine.

How can I make the view render once the promised hasMany relationship has been resolved using `view in views` for the `each` helper? Below are the relevant models and fixtures:

**displayItem model:**

```
var DisplayItem = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr("name"),
    display: DS.belongsTo("display", {async: true})
});
```

**chart model:**

```
var Chart = DisplayItem.extend({
    views: DS.hasMany("view", {async: true})
});
```

**view model:**

```
var View = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr("string"),
    chart: DS.belongsTo("chart", {async: true})
});
```

**relevant fixture data:**

```
Chart.FIXTURES = [
        {
            id: 1,
            name: "Derp",
            display: 1,
            views: [1, 2],
            defaultView: 1
        }
    ];

View.FIXTURES = [
        {
            id: 1,
            name: "Test 1",
            chart: 1
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            name: "Test 2",
            chart: 1
        }
    ];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, the route is simplest place to do it.  Using nested promises Ember won't setup the controller etc, until the deepest promise has resolved.

```
App.ChartContainerRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  model: function(){
    return this.store.find('chart').then(function(charts){
      return Em.RSVP.all(charts.getEach('views')).then(function(){
        return charts;
      });
    });
  }re
});
```

Generally I'd recommend against waiting on all of the async calls (since Ember will asynchronously inject them into the page).  If you are trying to modify the view after it's been inserted, there are other patterns that can solve this while giving a more responsive feeling app.

#### The real problem you're seeing

You aren't specifying anything to show in the li, and you're using a key word `view`

```
<li>{{view.name}}</li>
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/790/edit

`view` usually refers to the view associated with the current template etc.

```
    {{#each item in views}}
        <li>{{item}}</li>
    {{/each}}
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/791/edit

Comment: Thanks for the tip about `view` being a protected name--that occurred to me in the back of my mind when I was writing the code, but I didn't really think about it. Also, thanks for the explanation of the promise resolution chaining.